# How to setup mod_rewrite in server

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-hmvc

I have .htaccess file like this in my app. (only a sample for security)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /app_folder/ 

   #Removes access to the system folder by users.
   #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
   #previously this would not have been possible.
   #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

   #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
   #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
   #Submitted by: Fabdrol
   #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

   #Checks to 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]    

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
   # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
   # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

in (Rewritebase /app_folder/) what will i put in the app_folder name if my app is in the server? should i put the hostname in the app_folder? for example

```
  Rewritebase /http://example.com/
```

because my app_folder is now my webroot. I'm new in uploading my HMVC codeigniter setup in server using CentOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Ubuntu(linux):**

Run in terminal :

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

and then:

```
service apache2 restart
```

mod_rewrite will now be enabled!

---

**In Windows(wamp)**

You can manually edit the `httpd.conf` file

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf
```

This will open that file in notepad and you can locate the line
 #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
and remove the comment symbol '#' to activate the module. Then save the file and restart Apache to activate this change.

Comment: should i remove the app_folder name and just leave / (slash) like this RewriteBase /

Comment: If in root, just slash. If in some folder that is in server root, than `/foldername/`. So, I would say, in your case - just slash `/`.

Comment: Thanks dude you save my employment status LOL! :)